# Update git on centos 6 from 1.7.1 to 2.x

Tags: git, github

I am trying to take pull of my repository but getting this error:

```
error:  while accessing https://repository_name/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Checked for the solutions, so suggestions are to update git version.

```
yum update git
```

I tried above command but getting

```
No Packages marked for Update
```

Any thoughts?